# Videos are lagging in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, video, vlc

Videos are lagging in Ubuntu 18.04. Chrome, VLC and media, videos are lagging. The problem is not in the refresh rate, and it's not a network problem either. I tried to change the refresh rate, but it didn't help.

Comment: no, it's not a network problems. Because VLC is lagging too. few people have these problems too. But i didn't find answer in internet.

Comment: What happens after you try turning off hardware acceleration in Chrome advanced settings and restart Chrome? What happens after you turn it on and restart Chrome?

Comment: This problem is not isolated to the Chrome (and hence the acceleration settings in it)... Can you please specify whether you have recently installed any drivers which could have affected this? Thanks.